# Index to get row count of read-only (immutable) PostgreSQL table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a script that runs several times a day, which records the row counts of several PostgreSQL tables.

Some of the tables though are read-only and never change. (No rows are added or removed, nor are any values changed.)

Is there a way I could quickly get the row count from PostgreSQL? Eg. Could I create an index on `select count(*) from some_table;`?

I'd prefer not to cache this in the script. If I were to cache in the script, I haven't found a reliably way to determine if a table has been changed since the last time the script has run.

Comment: How much time does your count script take? How many row does the biggest table have? Which version of PostgreSQL are you using?

Comment: PostgreSQL version 9.4.4.

The biggest table has roughly 200MM rows, and counting it takes 10+ minutes.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, in postgresql SELECT COUNT(*) is often [slower than mysql](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans#Is_.22count.28.2A.29.22_much_faster_now.3F) to which it often get's compared to.

You can use the following query as an alternative to SELECT COUNT(*).

```
 SELECT reltuples FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'mytable';
```

This is not always 100% upto date but for immutable tables it will be accurate every time. And instant. For very large tables the percentage error will be very small and thus well worth the massive saving in time.

If it does matter and the table does not contain nulls, you can use

```
 SELECT COUNT(primary_key_column) FROM table
```

and this will be significantly faster than SELECT COUNT(*)

Comment: This is a pretty good answer; however, the script doesn't know which tables are immutable and which aren't. So the script wouldn't know when to run reltuples or when it would be necessary to count.

Also, reltuples::bigint was off by 6 rows on an immutable table with 200MM rows.

Comment: BTW 6 out of 200 million is only 0.000003%