# Improving Django Slice Step Performance

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I have an application where I am using a Django instance to store logs from a number of separate entities.  I then have a UX component that grabs log files from the django instance and graphs the values.  To keep things reasonable, I try to only grab a sample of the log values, then increase the granularity as the user zooms in.
My problem is that as the number of logs grows, the time to grab each downsampled group of logs is growing unsustainably.

Here is a simplified version of the model

```
class LogModel(models.Model):
   localtime = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
   value1 = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
   value1 = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
   value1 = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
   owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='logs')
```

Here is a sample query I use to get the data:

```
q = LogModel.objects.filter(owner=SomeOwner).order_by('localtime')
qNum = q.count()
logs = q[:qNum:(qNum/1000)]
```

Sometimes running this query takes a very long time (~16s).  The number of logs in a large device right now is ~150K.  If there are other things hitting the database, it can take a very long time (>1min).

Other information:
System:
VM w/ 2 CPU, 4GB RAM
DB: PostgreSQL 9.3
OS: Ubuntu 14.04

I have tried to follow the general optimizing the database guidelines, but with little luck.

Things that I have tried:
Increased the ram to the database.
Limiting the number of concurrent heavy database queries (3).

The total database is not very large, and should definitely fit into the 1GB I allocated to the database.  I feel like I am missing some very basic understanding of how this works, or a basic optimization.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, I thought you were running into a variation of the [postgresql slow count problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36925057/index-to-get-row-count-of-read-only-immutable-postgresql-table/36927941#36927941), because I misread the slicing to be taking a 1000 items from the tail of the queue. That itself would have been slow for two reasons; first the slow postgresql count already mentioned, Second  using a large offset causes the server to sort all the data and then skip ahead to that offset. But the slice you are taking is actually worse!!

```
qNum = q.count()
logs = q[:qNum:(qNum/1000)]
```

You are telling the ORM to count the number of rows (slow), And then to take every `nth` row from that. Unfortunately SQL language does not have built in support for a 'step' parameter to [LIMIT and OFFSET](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/queries-limit.html)

Slicing a django [queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/) to take every `nth` item is actually done in memory with in django and not at the RDBMS level. Django iterates through the entire queryset copying every nth item to a list and returns the list. So unsurprisingly it's slow. Indexes are useless because you are forcing the whole table to be read.

What I recommend is to use the [F expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-with-annotations) to apply a modulo operation on the primary key (for which you can create a [partial index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/indexes-partial.html) in postgresql).

```
LogModel.objects.annotate(idmod4=F('id') % 10).filter(idmod4=0)
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you.  Performance increase of 1000x.

Comment: glad to have been of help.

Comment: @e4c5 What would the code for the index creation look like in this case?