# Does cursor use less RAM then simple query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

If some query handles huge set of records(10 millions i.e.) and returns count(*)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from table
--10 joins
```

Is it true, that if I would use cursor to make count, then it could reduce RAM usage compared with simple query?

Comment: A cursor over 100 billion records? If you have a lot of time you will find out.  Cursors run  super long compared to a simple query

Comment: But what about RAM usage?

Comment: NEVER USE CURSORS IF YOU DONT HAVE TO. Who cares about RAM usage if the query runs for an day?

Comment: You have problems with memory? Memory is your friend if you run PG. If you need to limit memory usage then something is wrong. Why you want to lower memory usage?

Comment: @JosMac it is just theoretical question. One man tries to convince me that cursor is better for memory

Comment: Maybe the person is talking about saving client memory by paging through records, instead of retrieving a complete set. That *might* be a valid case.

However a count(*) only has to check for the existence of rows, and does not need to store any of the data from them in the way that selecting the row values would.

Comment: @SlavaNikulin Of course I do not know your whole query. But `count(*)` is one of the worst operations on data because it usually means `sequential scan` over whole table or all the partitions. If table has partitions then PG 9.6 can make it in parallel using parallel workers. In plain `count(*)` there is nothing on which you can safe memory. Because it does not do any sorts in memory etc.

Comment: @DavidAldridge so when I use COUNT(*) postgres does not store all data in memory first and then count it?

Comment: @SlavaNikulin What it does is quite complex, especially when there is a 10 table join to be executed, but to put it simply, no it doesn't need to store all the data in memory before counting. This is especially true if it only has to count the rows, not return any data from the table, as it can count the existence of the row and then no longer hold any data about it.

Comment: @SlavaNikulin As a general principle, you get the best performance by getting the work done in the database, not in external application code. This may not always be possible or desirable, as execution speed is not the only consideration, of course. Note also that questions like these should be fairly easy to test: create a table with 100GB of data in, and run a count against it. Did you use 100GB of memory? Nope.

Comment: @DavidAldridge thank you! So I guess, that cursor cannot reduce memory usage in this case, cause when pg runs count(*) it just makes sequential scan, that is i/o operation.

Comment: @SlavaNikulin "...  it just makes sequential scan, that is i/o operation ..." that's true for `SELECT COUNT(*) from table`, but less true if you're counting rows from a more complex query.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36925057/index-to-get-row-count-of-read-only-immutable-postgresql-table/36927941#36927941